# Meaning of 好感度高い in this context

Tags: meaning

To provide some context, the character was trying to scare away some hoodlums who had come to a abandoned mansion, by pretending to make noises that would make them think there was some sort of evil spirit there. One of the hoodlums claims to have 霊感 and is overreacting to everything that he hears. Towards the end of this exchange this hoodlum says "狐出てきた！？　絶対、呪うヤツじゃん" and the character thinks to himself "あいつは好感度高いな", and I'm struggling to understand what he means by this even after looking for word up online. It seems that it can be used to describe something or someone that makes/gives a really good impression or feeling, but this still leaves me struggling to interpret what he means in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

好感度(が)高い is "likable" or "affable", and it's normally not an adjective used to describe a hoodlum. The main character used it in this situation because he was feeling some sort of sympathy for the hoodlum's cowardly but humanly reaction.